# Weird load_module input parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, python-import

I have written a custom Python module loader/importer which has find_module and load_module methods. I run into a bit of a problem when I want to import Cherrypy module with it.

In

> cherrypy/__ init __.py

it has lines such as:

```
from cherrypy._cpcompat import urljoin
```

When I use the default Python importer, only adding a fake importer such as:

```
class FakeImporter(object):
  def find_module(self, module_name, path=None):
    print module_name, path
    return None
```

I get following calls:

> find_module('cherrypy')
>
> find_module('cherrypy.cherrypy')
>
> find_module('cherrypy._cpcompat')

Sounds normal. But when I use my custom loader I get calls:

> find_module('cherrypy')
>
> find_module('cherrypy.cherrypy')
>
> find_module('cherrypy.cherrypy._cpcompat')

What could be causing this issue? Am I handling the load_module('cherrypy.cherrypy') wrong? I load the module from memory, so set cherrypy.**path** to ['cherrypy'], also set **file** to 'cherrypy', **loader** to my loader, **name** to 'cherrypy' and **package** to 'cherrypy'. Is there something missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong: in my find_module I always returned my importer, what effectively blocked the absolute imports from ever happening.